# How to get the clicked menu item's $mlid in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, menu, submenu

I'm trying to build a submenu based on `$mlid`. I've found a function that appears to do the job, but I just can't seem to figure out how to get the `$mlid` of the menu item that was just clicked.

I found the function in a link on similar post here on SO (http://drupal.org/node/249257), but I can only find examples where the $mlid is set manually. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `menu_get_item()` function to get information about the current page as a menu item, then make a query to the database to get the mlid.

```
$item = menu_get_item(); //Gets menu_router information for current page
$mlid = db_result(db_query("SELECT mlid FROM {menu_links} WHERE link_path='%s'", $item['path']));
```

Note - this applies to Drupal 6.

Comment: that code is missing single quotes around the %s and is also missing a ending parenthesis to close the db_result function

Answer (score 4):

The idea behind emmychan's solution is great, but contains errors. So I rewrote it for Drupal 7's database api:

```
$mlid = db_select('menu_links' , 'ml')
  ->condition('ml.link_path' , $_GET['q'])
  ->fields('ml' , array('mlid'))
  ->execute()
  ->fetchField();
```

EDIT: To make the snippet more versatile like Ambidex suggests I updated the code so it uses `$_GET['q']` to try to get the MLID of the current page.

Comment: This approach will always assume that the currect active page is a node, in a lot of pages this will not work. (eg. `/user`)

Answer (score 3):

I advice you to use: [`menu_get_active_trail()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_active_trail/7)

You'll get the current `$mlid`.

It's for Drupal 7.

Answer (score 2):

This is based off of Imeurs code for Drupal 7. If you don't know the $nid, or will be using this with panels pages, you can get the current item using the following code:

```
$item =  menu_get_item();    
$mlid = db_select('menu_links' , 'ml')
  ->condition('ml.link_path' , $item['href'])
  ->fields('ml' , array('mlid'))
  ->execute()
  ->fetchField();
```

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you really looking for the [Menu Block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module?